# Admin only navigation widget

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a little admin-only navigation panel for my site that should only be visible when an admin has logged in. I have all the session logic working fine I just am not sure on one thing.

Is it more standard practice to have the navigation panel HTML code always in the source, but just change the display property using PHP based on whether or not the user is logged in as admin? So something like

```
<head>
<?php 
   if($_SESSION['loggedin']) { 
     echo "<style>#adminPanel { display:block; }</style>";
   }
?>
</head>
```

while having the original CSS `display:none;`?

or

having PHP echo the full adminPanel HTML if the user is logged in?
Like:

```
<?php
  if($_SESSION['loggedin'])
  {
     ?>

        //HTML for adminPanel goes here

     <?php
  }
?>
```

I basically want to know what method is standard, or if they are equally acceptable?
Thanks

I am not sure if this question is considered subjective, so sorry if it is.

Comment: Do not simply hide the panel via CSS, as anyone who looks at the source code or the active DOM could easily enable the visual component.

Comment: oh that is a very good point, thank you

Comment: No problem, it'll save you the headache of some unauthorized users attempting to run commands they shouldn't be :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users can edit CSS on-the-fly and expose your admin panel in the first method. Therefore, the second is preferable since you won't be outputting anything you don't want the user to see.

Comment: I did not even think about that. It makes a lot more sense to use the second then. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If something is supposed to be not-visible for unauthorized people, then don't sent it to the client in the first place. It may be security by-obscurity, but why brag about the fact that there IS an admin panel and say exactly where it is?

Answer (score 1):

I might be sleeping, but isn't the two doing the exact same thing, but the first example is simply echoing the HTML-markup?

To answer your question:

I usually wrap all elements that are supposed to have some form of access-rights tied to them like you've done in example #2. Makes it alot easier to read, and saves you a headache when you inevitably miss one of the quotation marks.

You could also make a simple "include if logged in" such as:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['loggedin']{

    include('/path/to/adminpanel.php');
}
?>
```

Wich is my general approach since it simplifies updates and changes even more. This also means that the JS you want to include that are specific to the admin panel will be invisible to the standard user, since that would be requested within the "adminpanel.php"

Comment: yes, they do both the same thing, the first one has the HTML in the source, but is just display:none;